# Can TCAS and GPWS work at the same time?

Tags: aircraft-performance, navigation, airline-pilot, maneuver

A manoeuvre to avoid a collision with terrain, might put you onto a collision course with traffic above you.

Can TCAS and (E)GPWS work at the same time? Are they coordinating?

Comment: Do you have a valid reason to believe that they might not?

Comment: (See chat -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61400721#61400721 and subsequent (may wrap to "next day"))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes they can work together. It's not particularly sophisticated. Essentially there is a priority list for all alerts.

For TAWS/GPWS and TCAS, the TAWS/GPWS alerts will take precedence over a TCAS RA (the ground isn't going to move out of your way.) When the TAWS/GPWS issues an alert, a signal is sent to the TCAS to force it into TA-Only Mode.

When a TCAS is in TA Only mode, it can only issue TAs which are advisory and require no action. It will also communicate the fact it's in TA-Only mode to any other TCAS equipped aircraft that may present a conflict. If a conflict does arise, the TCAS (on the terrain avoiding aircraft) will generate a TA and the other aircraft will generate a non-cooperative RA. A non-cooperative RA is the same as what happens when a conflict arises with a non-TCAS equipped aircraft.

Comment: Is there any means via which the crew of an aircraft can indicate to the TCAS system that their ability to maneuver the aircraft is extremely limited (e.g. due to mechanical problems)?

Comment: Like, not reacting to the TCAS? It will eventually get it, and reverse the advisory on the other aircraft.

Comment: @supercat Yes. The crew can manually select TA-Only mode for the TCAS. That mode information is sent to any nearby TCAS-equipped aircraft that are potentially in conflict. Normal TCAS conflict resolution will result in coordinated RAs in both aircraft. TA-Only mode tells the other aircraft they have to resolve the conflict without a coordinated RA. Their TCAS assumes the TA-Only aircraft will continue on it's present track, updating its guidance as it tracks the aircraft.

Comment: @Haukinger The aircraft responding to the TAWS/GPWS alert will take no action based on the TA. Their job at that moment is to avoid hitting the ground. The other aircraft would get a TCAS RA that it would respond to to avoid the suddenly climbing aircraft. Once the aircraft has climbed sufficiently for the TAWS/GPWS alert to go away, their TCAS will revert normal TA/RA mode, at which time they could receive an RA if the conflict still exists. Since the TCAS gets raw Radio Altitude data, it won't issue a descend RA if it's below the minimum altitude.

Comment: For clarity, "TA-Only" is "Terrain Avoidance-only" and "RA" is "Resolution Advisory"?

Comment: @FreeMan "TA" mode is a TCAS Traffic Advisory mode. RA is a TCAS  Resolution Advisory mode.

Comment: @Gerry: Is switching of the TCAS system into that mode an early part of responding to unexpected control problems?  I know that the general rule is "Aviate; Navigate; Communicate", but I would think that communicating as quickly as possible a message "Look out everyone!  I can't control this thing!" should take priority over almost everything else, but should be easy enough as to not interfere with doing anything else.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure about "control problems", but switching TCAS to "TA only" is on every engine failure checklist I've seen (since you cannot climb at your normal rate after a single engine failure).

Comment: @Bianfable: I was thinking of more general situations where the aircraft might become hard to control, or where a pilot might want to minimize stress on the air frame, e.g. because a pilot hears a loud bang followed by what seems to be excessive vibration.  Having pilots instinctively hit a button as their first action when something unexpected happens, even before they know what it is, would help ensure that they're not hit with a TCAS RA alert that other planes would expect them to follow.

Comment: @supercat There are some things you had better do right away as memory items (e.g. reduce AOA upon incipient stall), but it's hard for me to to imagine switching to "TA only" being one of those things, especially when you don't even know what kind of issue you're dealing with yet.

Comment: @WayneConrad: If switching would require navigating through multiple menus, having that be a priority might be misplaced.  If switching would simply require hitting a Big Red Button, then having a policy "if in doubt, HIT THE BUTTON" would seem pretty straightforward.  Switching TCAS to TA-only mode in a situation where it turns out to have been unnecessary may be discourteous to other aircraft, but shouldn't cause any harm beyond requiring a pilot to issue an official explanation as to why the button was hit.  Such a button could also help guard against loss of CVR/FDR recordings...

Comment: ...in cases where a plane has a problem but ends up landing normally, and would generally seem advantageous.

Comment: @supercat I don't know all the emergency conditions that would justify switching to TA-Only mode, but as Bianfable indicated any time you can't climb as with an engine out it would be appropriate. An emergency descent may be another. As for switching modes, in most aircraft the mode selector is a rotary switch on the ATC/TCAS control panel in the center console (typically just below the throttles.) The typical switch options are TEST-STDBY-XPDR-TA Only-TA/RA so switching is one click of the knob.